# Can I post my program that Stack Overflow has helped build?

Tags: discussion

A lot of my questions are about hobby projects and the game I am making. As this site has helped so much in their production, I thought I'd give back by publishing the ones I can on here, so the people that helped me can enjoy the fruits of their labour so to speak.

But I was wondering if this is frowned upon, as it is sort of like marketing my stuff.

So what is the general consensus on the subject, are there rules to follow, or is it outright banned?

Comment: This is a Q&A site. What question could you possibly ask when posting the application? Host it on github and tell people about it on your blog or a forum.

Comment: If you publish it to Git / Bitbucket, chat would be an excellent place to let people know it exists. Just take care not to overly promote it.

Comment: I would imagine that posting a link to the project in this question would be a good idea. (In a comment probably.)

Comment: **Your public profile** would be an even better place to tell people about it and post a link than chat. That way, others will see it, even if they don't happen to be in the chat room at that particular time.

Answer (score 13):

I don't see where this would be on-topic and suitable on Stack Overflow - a software contribution would be likely closed as off-topic very quickly.

Consider publishing it as Open Source on a specialized platform like Github, and posting the link in your bio.

You can also link to it when asking a question related to it, but tread carefully - no matter how good your intentions, if the community thinks it sees advertising, it tends to respond with hostility.

Comment: Best to leave comments pimping your project than actual answers.  At least you can't get spamvoted into nonexistence via comment flags.

Comment: thats what i was worried about :( I just wanted to say thanks to the people that helped

Comment: Also, shouldn't your account be called "Pekka's Twister Pimping Account?"

Comment: @Won't I just want to share the love! (Although a pimp might say the same thing. Hmmm.)

Comment: @EatmoreTwisters: Pimping doesn't always have to have a negative connotation.  In fact, I'm going to be keeping my eye out for Twisters.  And hoes.  But that's nothing different.

Comment: @Skeith: To say "thank you", you could add the link in comments to the answers which most helped you.

Answer (score 7):

Feel free to put a link to your project in the *"About Me"* box of your profile. That is exactly the kind of thing for which it is provided.